# PHP DateDifference to integer

Tags: php, datetime

I have a simple routine that gets the number of days from a date for completion against today:

```
$datetime1 = date_create("$todaydb");
$datetime2 = date_create("$date2");
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
```

This fine and works OK but I simply want to get the interval as an integer s I can decide on the colour of the text.

It's driving me mad!

Comment: you can use timestamps 
$interval=$datetime1->format("U")-$datetime2->format("U");

Comment: What is within `$todaydb` and `$date2`. Post that too

Answer (score 1):

use `strtotime()` for this.

```
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo strtotime($interval);
```

Comment: did not work - got an error message ; Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in xxxx on line 55

Comment: before that `strtotime()` , add echo $interval;

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$diff = $datetime2->diff($datetime1)->format("%a");
```

$diff should give you an integer value.

Comment: No problem. Can you make it as an answer if you're happy with this solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to generate the timestamps for both dates and then subtract one from the other.

Pseudo Code:

```
$t1 = mktime(...parms1...);
$t2 = mktime(...parms2...);
$diff = $t2 - $t1;
```